# How to use a relative path from web.config runtime linkedConfiguration

Tags: .net, web-config, assembly-binding-redirect

I am attempting to use a relative path with the [`<linkedConfiguration>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/linkedconfiguration-element) element. I am able to specify a full path to my runtime.config and it will load it fine but I would like to set this relative to the AppBase which is displayed in the fusion log. I have tried the following.

```
<linkedConfiguration href="file:runtime.config"/>
<linkedConfiguration href="file://./runtime.config"/>
<linkedConfiguration href="runtime.config"/>
<linkedConfiguration href="./runtime.config"/>
<linkedConfiguration href="~/runtime.config"/>
```

I also found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128049/using-relative-path-in-assemblybindig-linkedconfiguration-element) but unfortunately it did not work for me. This is the only path that has worked for me so far.

```
<linkedConfiguration href="file://C:/Perforce/{product}/Branches/Working26/UI/Web/{website}/runtime.config"/>
```

The `{}` are for information I redacted from the URL.

Here is where I put the [`<linkedConfiguration>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/linkedconfiguration-element) in my web.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  ...
  <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
     <linkedConfiguration href="file://C:/Perforce/{product}/Branches/Working26/UI/Web/{website}/runtime.config"/>
  </assemblyBinding>
</configuration>
```

and here is the runtime.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    ...
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Lumberjack" culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="bef447dd453f4f84" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-12.400.0.0" newVersion="12.400.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
    ...
  </runtime>
<configuration>
```

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: @camainc No unfortunately I never found a means to do this.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work for web.config files. I think because the parent element is "runtime" and not "configuration."

Comment: See answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32128049/using-relative-path-in-assemblybindig-linkedconfiguration-element/59679518#59679518